# SpreadsheetApp how to use variable inside formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, formulas

I want to be able to put my variable row into the

```
.setValue("=SUM(B54:BA54)")
```

Actually I need the value of row to replace `B54:B54`. I'm looking for something like

```
.setValue("=SUM(B+row+:BA+row)")
```

So if `row = 50` the `setValue` will put `=SUM(B50:BA50)` in the cell

```
var text3 = result3.getResponseText();
var row = parseInt(text3);
activeSheet.getRange(row+3,55).setValue("=SUM(B54:BA54)");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var text3 = result3.getResponseText();
var row = parseInt(text3);
activeSheet.getRange(row+3,55).setValue("=SUM(B" + row + ":BA" + row + ")");
```

using concatenation should work like you want it.

Comment: Yes it is thanks, and since i need row+3, i just add " + (row+3) + "

Comment: @MaximeMorin-Gagnon If it works, you can accept my answer.